# echoing a php code to html file while executing php script

Tags: php, printing, echo

iam writing a php script and i want that script to execute and then the executed result will be saved to another file and then it will redirect to that save file.

now my problem is script that iam executing have some php code that i need to be saved as it is in the saved file

```
<?php
function ago($time)
{
   $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
   $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

   $now = time();

       $difference     = $now - $time;
       $tense         = "ago";

   for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
       $difference /= $lengths[$j];
   }

   $difference = round($difference);

   if($difference != 1) {
       $periods[$j].= "s";
   }

   return "$difference $periods[$j] 'ago' ";
}
?>
```

iam trying to echo these line from the executing script so that the above lines can be saved.
 and iam doing it like this.

```
   <?php 
            function rowFromVar($last_modified) {
              $result  = " <?php   $$last_modified = filemtime(__FILE__);

                function ago($time)
                    {
                       $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
                       $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

                       $now = time();

                           $difference     = $now - $time;
                           $tense         = "ago";

                       for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
                           $difference /= $lengths[$j];
                       }

                       $difference = round($difference);

                       if($difference != 1) {
                           $periods[$j].= "s";
                       }

                       return "$difference $periods[$j] 'ago' ";
                    }
                    $last=ago($last_modified);";

     return $result;

    }
    print rowFromVar("last_modified");
```

but iam having some errors like

```
    ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\SEO stat[Repica OF     server]\Tools\domain_lookup1.php on line 109
```

any help would be appreciated .

Comment: check your syntax. you just made a little error, see the code highlighting where it breaks.

Comment: Also nowdoc or heredoc strings are probably more useful for what you're trying to do: http://php.net/string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
        function rowFromVar($last_modified) {
          $result  = <<<XXX_DELIMETER_XXX
<?php   \$last_modified = filemtime(__FILE__);

            function ago(\$time)
                {
                   \$periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
                   \$lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

                   \$now = time();

                       \$difference     = \$now - \$time;
                       \$tense         = "ago";

                   for(\$j = 0; \$difference >= \$lengths[\$j] && \$j < count(\$lengths)-1; \$j++) {
                       \$difference /= \$lengths[\$j];
                   }

                   \$difference = round(\$difference);

                   if(\$difference != 1) {
                       \$periods[\$j].= "s";
                   }
XXX_DELIMETER_XXX;
                   return "$difference $periods[$j] 'ago' ";
                }
                $last=ago($last_modified);";

 return $result;

}
print rowFromVar("last_modified");
```

It should work, And u are using unescaped Double Quotes..

if helped please use the +1 button

Comment: output saved but name of variables are missing.    >>. output is like    <?php   $last_modified = filemtime(__FILE__);

            function ago()
                {
                    = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
                    = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");
 
                   =time();    it should be like   $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
                   $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

Comment: I edited it again... Actually You have to type \$ when you want to **output** a $ sign... And By chance I edited all the $ signs ... If you want some of them to be variables, just remove the \ before the $... Like \$difference=$now-$time will simply search for two vars $now and $time and will replace.. And it was my fault that I haven't escaped $s...